# Touchable presses not firing in absolute positioned container with zIndex (for a dropdown)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been trying to tweak the styles and elements render order so that Android and iOS behave the same. Did a lot of research and the current answers don't seem to solve the issue.

- **Product**: I am writing a cross platform dropdown component
- **Issue/Behavior**: On iOS the presses fire correctly, however on android they fall off.
- **Example**: [Here is a codepen showing what it should do](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWopew) **Please fork it if you want to make changes on the codepen**

The issue is **this exact code works on iOS but not on an Android device**.

```
class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      selected: undefined,
    }
  }

  handleSelectPress = () => {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  }
  handleOptionPress = (item) => {
    this.setState({selected: item, open: !this.state.open});
    this.props.onSelectOption(item);
  }
  render () {
    const { selected = {}, open } = this.state
    const { placeholder = '', options = [] } = this.props

    return (
      <Select
        onPress={this.handleSelectPress}
        value={selected.name || placeholder}
        open={open}
        options={options}
        onOptionPress={this.handleOptionPress} />
    )
  }
}

const shadowStyles = {
  ios: {
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    shadowOffset: {
        height: 1,
        width: 1,
    },
  },
  android: {
    elevation: 5,
  },
}

class Select extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    const { value, open, options, onOptionPress } = this.props
    const shadowStyle = shadowStyles[Platform.OS]
    return (
      <View style={[shadowStyle, styles.wrap]}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.props.onPress}>
          <View style={styles.selectContainer}>
            <Text>{value}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        {open && <View style={styles.menu}>
          { options.map( (item, idx) => <Option value={item} key={idx} onPress={onOptionPress} />)}
        </View>}
      </View>

    )
  }
}

class Option extends React.PureComponent {
  handlePress = () => {
    this.props.onPress(this.props.value)
  }
  render () {
    const { value } = this.props
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress}>
        <View style={styles.optionContainer}>
          <Text>{value.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <Dropdown
          placeholder="--- SELECT ---"
          options={
            [
              { name: "Press me!", id: "1" },
              { name: "No Me!", id: "2" },
              { name: "Cmon guys, here!", id: "3" },
            ]
          }
          onSelectOption={ (item) => console.log(`item pressed! ${item}`)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    root: {
      width: 360,
      height: 640,
      backgroundColor: '#292c2e'
    },
    wrap: {
      position: 'relative',
      zIndex: 10,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(73,75,77)'
    },
    selectContainer: {
      padding: 16,
    },
    menu: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(73,75,77)',
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '100%',
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      maxHeight: 300
    },
    optionContainer: {
      padding: 16
    }

  });
```

**React Native version - 0.59.3**

Few things to note:

- I'm not looking for a package that already does this.
- I'm using `zIndex` so that the menu element is rendered on top of other elements (rendered after the dropdown component).
- I tried using `TouchableHighlight`, `TouchableOpacity`, `TouchableWithoutFeedback` and for android only `TouchableNativeFeedback`
- I tried changing the "menu" element between a `View` and a `ScrollView` (initially was scroll)
- I played around with elevation and z-index on the option / touchables
- The touch on the `Select` that toggles the `open` flag works properly on both Android and iOS so I'm pretty sure its narrowed down to an absolute positioned parent.
- I'm planning on adding animations, polishing the styles... etc (acutally using styled-components in the project). But first need it to function :D

Comment: maybe try using one of the other touchable variants?  e.g. `<TouchableOpacity>` instead of `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>`

Comment: I tried all of those @MikeM was actually editing the question to include that detail when you posted :D

Comment: So event handler not working, but what about visual feedback when pressed, did you see it?

Comment: No, the press is not firing / being recognized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set position for `Select` instead of `Option`

here is a snack: https://snack.expo.io/HkDHHo6YV

change `wrap` and `menu` style with given below:

```
wrap: {
  position: 'absolute',
  zIndex: 10,
  width: "100%",
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(73,75,77)',
},
menu: {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(73,75,77)',
  maxHeight: 300,
},
```

---

#### Edit, Working solution

The missing piece was to account for the space under the dropdown since it was completely absolutely positioned. I had to change the `Select` component to render a "padding" element to account for the space.

```
class Select extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { value, open, options, onOptionPress } = this.props;
    const shadowStyle = shadowStyles[Platform.OS];
    return (
      <>
        <View style={{height: 60}}></View>
        <View style={[shadowStyle, styles.wrap]}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.props.onPress}>
            <View style={styles.selectContainer}>
              <Text>{value}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          {open && (
            <View style={styles.menu}>
              {options.map((item, idx) => (
                <Option value={item} key={idx} onPress={onOptionPress} />
              ))}
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Then adjusted the height of the `styles.selectContainer` to be the same height `60`

```
selectContainer: {
  padding: 16,
  height: 60
},
```

---

#### Full working example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Button,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      selected: undefined,
    };
  }

  handleSelectPress = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };
  handleOptionPress = item => {
    this.setState({ selected: item, open: !this.state.open });
    this.props.onSelectOption(item);
  };
  render() {
    const { selected = {}, open } = this.state;
    const { placeholder = '', options = [] } = this.props;

    return (
      <Select
        onPress={this.handleSelectPress}
        value={selected.name || placeholder}
        open={open}
        options={options}
        onOptionPress={this.handleOptionPress}
      />
    );
  }
}

const shadowStyles = {
  ios: {
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 1,
    },
  },
  android: {
    elevation: 5,
  },
};

class Select extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { value, open, options, onOptionPress } = this.props;
    const shadowStyle = shadowStyles[Platform.OS];
    return (
      <>
        <View style={{height: 60}}></View>
        <View style={[shadowStyle, styles.wrap]}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.props.onPress}>
            <View style={styles.selectContainer}>
              <Text>{value}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          {open && (
            <View style={styles.menu}>
              {options.map((item, idx) => (
                <Option value={item} key={idx} onPress={onOptionPress} />
              ))}
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class Option extends React.PureComponent {
  handlePress = () => {
    this.props.onPress(this.props.value);
  };
  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress}>
        <View style={styles.optionContainer}>
          <Text>{value.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <Dropdown
          placeholder="--- SELECT ---"
          options={[
            { name: 'Press me!', id: '1' },
            { name: 'No Me!', id: '2' },
            { name: 'Cmon guys, here!', id: '3' },
          ]}
          onSelectOption={item => console.log(`item pressed! ${item}`)}
        />
        <Text>hellof</Text>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: "red", height: 250}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    width: 360,
    height: 640,
    backgroundColor: '#292c2e',
    marginTop: 100
  },
  wrap: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 10,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(73,75,77)',
  },
  selectContainer: {
    padding: 16,
    height: 60
  },
  menu: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(73,75,77)',
    maxHeight: 300,
  },
  optionContainer: {
    padding: 16,
    height: 60
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Everything looks like it works, i'll port it over to my app and verify real quick. Looks promising!

Comment: So looking at the styles (haven't run it in the app yet), elements would fall underneath the dropdown because its completely absolutely positioned. Thats not a deal breaker because I can put an element underneath that in the `Dropdown` component that is the same height. I'll edit your answer with those details when I write it <3

Comment: Thanks for your help getting me to the right place! After Jaydeeps answer I could have probably figured it out but haven't had time to work on it. Updated your answer with the working example!

Comment: Perfect, I have just updated snack link with an example you have given

Comment: There was one more issue I was trying to figure out. Its a bug in how `styled-components` applies styles I guess. Seems like the `zIndex` was not being set when on a `Wrap` styled component. Very strange but im just going to use the `StyleSheet` method for that one element :) Thanks again, rewarded you with the $$ :D

Comment: @ShashinBhayani what if I need that space? 
Is there any solution for this case? 
```<View style={{height: 60}}></View>```

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your styles in `styles.menu` not with zIndex.

You have given `position:'absolute'` and `top:'100%'`.

This means your child view is positioned as absolute to the parent view and your child view will start right after your parent view is completing because of `top:"100%"`.

**Conclusion**: your options are rendering out of the parent. yes, they are visible because there are no other components below and more of that zIndex is higher. and you can not touch anything that is not withing the range of parent.

**Solution**:

[See working snack here](https://snack.expo.io/@jdgalani6297/view-out-of-parent)

in styles.menu, change these,

```
  menu: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(73,75,77)',
    zIndex: 1005,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    maxHeight: 300,
  },
```

and you can remove zIndex: 1000 and 1005 also :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! (zIndex was for testing purposes, plan is to only have one specified on the parent). Totally forgot about presses outside of the container for android! However, theres still an issue. Please reference my request for the bounty "Would like to have a normal dropdown element (**menu folds on top of other elements... etc)**". With your answer, how does it behave as a dropdown if its not absolutely positioned? It will bump content if you render elements after the dropdown.